# Need help reading using LINQ to XML reading XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML File:

```
<DATASET>
<MESSAGE TYPE="TYPE1 ">
<FROM>
</FROM>
<EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<TO>
email@email.com
</TO>
</EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<SUBJECT>
tHIS IS A SUBJECT
</SUBJECT>
<BODY>
THIS is the bidoy
</BODY>
<ATTACHED>
<CONTENT>                this is some content                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content                </CONTENT>
</ATTACHED>
</MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE TYPE="TYPE1 ">
<FROM>
</FROM>
<EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<TO>
email2@email.com
</TO>
</EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<SUBJECT>
this IS A SUBJECT
</SUBJECT>
<BODY>
THIS is the body
</BODY>
<ATTACHED>
<CONTENT>                this is some content2                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content2                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content2                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content2                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content2               </CONTENT>
</ATTACHED>
</MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE TYPE="TYPE1 ">
<FROM>
</FROM>
<EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<TO>
email3@email.com
</TO>
</EMAILRECIPIENTS>
<SUBJECT>
tHIS IS A SUBJECT
</SUBJECT>
<BODY>
THIS is the body3
</BODY>
<ATTACHED>
<CONTENT>                this is some content3                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content3                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content3                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content3                </CONTENT>
<CONTENT>                this is some content3                </CONTENT>
</ATTACHED>
</MESSAGE>
</DATASET>
```

Now I have tried to write a class to store this information:

```
public class Dataset
{
public List<Message> Messages = new List<Message>();
}

public class Message
{
public string MessageType { get; set;}
public string From { get; set; }
public string Recipients { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Body { get; set; }
public string Attachmentfilename { get; set; }
public string Record { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my main I tried this:

```
 List<Message> messagelist = new List<Message(
 (
 from e in XDocument.Load(@"c:\XML\1.XML").Descendants("DATASET")
 select new Message
 {
   MessageType = e.Element("MESSAGE").Attribute("TYPE").Value,
   From = e.Element("MESSAGE").Element("FROM").Value,
   Subject = e.Element("MESSAGE").Element("SUBJECT").Value,
   Body = e.Element("MESSAGE").Element("BODY").Value,
   AttachmentFileName = e.Element("MESSAGE").Element("ATTACHEMENT").Attribute("FILENAME").Value,
   Record = e.Element("MESSAGE").Element("ATTACHEMENT").ELement("CONTENT").Value
 }).ToList());
```

Now I trimed the values I was getting top just make my point. Am I going about doing this all wrong. I just want to parse the XML file to a list or something that I can then go through and send emails based on the values.

My idea is to take the XML file which could contain one record, or many records. My code isn't working and it is mostly due to me not really knowing what I am doing, any advice on the way to process this, or to use LINQ to XML to parse this file noted above would be great.

I have this running, but it only seems to pull the first message into the list and only the first line of CONTENT.

I am looing to pull the whole XML file to the list, the XML file can have multiple Messages. could be one, could have 20.

I would like the list to accept more than one message, this code only seems to pull the first one.

I would like the CONTENT output to one document where each  is a line item which preserves whitespace and each line.

What can I change to make this accept more than one line of the CONTENT and more than one message?

Comment: Please format your code and your XML - it's really hard to read with no indentation. Additionally "my code isn't working" doesn't tell us anything about what you're trying to achieve vs what actually happens.

Comment: There's no `RECORD` element in your XML. If you want to create a list of `Message` have you already considered using Xml De-Serialization instead of writing all the boilerplate code to assign the properties?

Comment: What you are seeing was typos I fixed them, but they are not my issue. My issues is I am trying this approach and it is not working I get object not set.

Comment: @Filburt, I would love to learn the LINQ TO XML way to do this, but am open to Anything at this point. I simply want to read through the XML file and process it to an email, I just cannot figure out how to get the LINQ TO XML to a list and then to the processing, right now I cannot even seem to get it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment I'd rather have the XmlSerializer do the job:

Your Message class

```
[XmlType("MESSAGE")]
public class Message
{
    [XmlElement("FROM")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("EMAILRECIPIENTS")]
    [XmlArrayItem("TO")]
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SUBJECT")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BODY")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ATTACHED")]
    [XmlArrayItem("CONTENT")]
    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

... and using XmlSerializer is as simple as

```
var msgs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Message>), new XmlRootAttribute("DATASET"));

using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\XML\1.XML"))
{
    var messages = msgs.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, but  msgs is not decleared. in the line var messages = msgs.Deserialize(sr) . I tried changing msgs to ser.Deserialize and got 0. Cannot get this to work...

Comment: My bad - fiddled around with code after pasting my tested solution. `msgs` is of course the XmlSerializer instance you create in the first line. Do you get an error or is the result simply an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are no closing `</MESSAGE>`.
Second, your `<MESSAGE>` does not have `<RECORD>`.
Check your XML again. There is no obvious problem in your code.

Comment: I fixed that, but not my issue, just a typo trying to type it out

Comment: Also try to replace `.Descendants("DATASET")` with `.Element("DATASET").Elements("MESSAGE")`

Comment: And of course `e.Element("CONTENT")` with `e.Element("ATTACHED").Element("CONTENT")`

Comment: This is just a typo, in the original files that isn't like that. I had to type it all out and made some mistakes typing it out, could not copy and paste due to security. I will take another look at this and clean it up.

Comment: I updated my code and questions, sorry for any confusion. My issue is that it only pulls the first message and the first line of the CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

the xml document has a tag called `EMAILRECIPIENTS` but the Dataset class has no matching property - it only has `Recipients`

Also in your code you have the following line

```
Record = e.ELement("CONTENT").Value
```

but in the XML file, all the `Content` tags are children of an `Attached` tag

Comment: Does it really make a difference what I call EMAILRECIPIENT it in my class, I just felt like shortening it? As for the Content, good catch, maybe that is part of why I am getting the error.

Comment: I updated my code and questions, sorry for any confusion. My issue is that it only pulls the first message and the first line of the CONTENT.

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's clean up your code. You have too many unnecessary things, and are referencing the wrong values. There are no FROM, SUBJECT, CONTENT in the element DATASET. Some of these are children of MESSAGE, and CONTENT is a child of ATTACHED,

```
List<Message> messagelist = XElement.Load(file)
    .Descendants("MESSAGE")
    .Select(e => new Message
    {
       From = e.Element("FROM").Value,
       Subject = e.Element("SUBJECT").Value,
       Record = string.Join("\n", e.Descendants("CONTENT")
                                   .Select(c => c.Value)
                                   .ToArray())
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I updated my code and questions, sorry for any confusion. My issue is that it only pulls the first message and the first line of the CONTENT.

Comment: @JohnDoyal well, mine fixes that. It gets every MESSAGE and every CONTENT line. The only thing to adjust is if you want a new line between each CONTENT or a space, but you can adjust that yourself.